# Making Browser Auto-Scroll to Most Recently Submitted Comment

Tags: php, mysql

I made a comment on a Wordpress blog and I noticed that after I submitted the comment, the top of the browser was flush with the top of my comment.  In other words, the web page was auto-scrolled down to the top of my comment.

How can I do this?  I am using a comment system with PHP / MySQL.

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 2):

Use an [anchor](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3) and try to redirect adding the anchor to your link.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/questions/2301455#comment-54564');
```

should work.

Else you can do it with javascript by setting the hash property of the location object.

```
location.hash = '#comment-54564';
```

or using jQuery :

```
$(location).attr('hash', '#comment-54564');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<a name="latest_comment">Comment goes here</a>
```

And then after a user posts a comment, redirect them to:

```
http://www.your-domain.com/your-uri#latest_comment
```

Check out this link under the "name attribute" section:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: How would I apply the "latest_comment" to only the most recent comment?

Comment: You would only apply it to the very last/first comment, depending on if the comments were sorted in ascending/descending order (by date) when you queried the database. Maybe you could add some code to your original question to give a more concrete example of where you're having difficulty?

Comment: I posted the code in another question.  I would appreciate it if you would take a look at it.